# use promise for ajax plus timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, requestanimationframe

I am writing a script that makes an async call to grab a bunch of array data (~50,000 items), iterates with that data using requestanimationframe() a bunch of times, then makes another call and iterates through those results, several times.

I want to start iterating through the data from subsequent calls as soon as possible after I've finished the requestanimationframe looping with the previous batch.  What I'd like is to make the async call for the next batch while the first batch is being worked on, then start working on the next as soon as both 1) that call returns and 2) the requestanimationframe() iteration completes.

I'm using jquery.  If I were waiting for 2 ajax calls, I'd use $.when() and done().  But my second condition isn't an ajax return.  I want to avoid something klugey like checking with setInterval() for the second condition after the first one is met.

right now my code is something like:

```
function doIt(value){
  $.get("bunch/of/data.php", {param:value}, function(data){
    var t;
    var tt = 0;
    function process(){
      if(tt < 3000) {
        requestAnimationFrame(process)
      }
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      tt += (now - (t || now)); // + ms since last frame called
      t = now;
      //...do a bunch of stuff with data
      if(tt >= 3000){
        doIt(newValue)
      }
    }
    process();
  }
}
```

This results in waiting for the data call, then processing with it, then waiting for the next data call, etc.

Comment: how often will you be making the ajax call? a set frequency? or does that depend on the progress of the "bunch of stuff"

Comment: and how is `newValue` determined?

Comment: currently, the next ajax call is made once tt >=3000 (i.e., after 3 seconds); you can assume newValue is just incremented to grab the next set of data.

Comment: yes, I understand what your code does - I'm asking what you *want* - i.e. it looks like you want the code to initiate the next ajax at the start of processing the current ajax results

Comment: another possibility is to get the ajax continuously while processing an ever increasing "queue" of data - there's no indication in your code, however, as to how the processing of a single request is determined to be complete ... or is it a case of you wanting to process each request for 3 seconds then abandoning that data, and process the next request for 3 seconds - there's a few ways to interpret your code and your question, so please clarify

Comment: Yes, it's the latter — after 3s I'm done with one batch of data and on to the next.  I could continuously make ajax calls, but 1) that'll end up with an awful lot of data in the client, at 50k items or so per call, and 2) I'll still need to make sure the appropriate one of those calls has returned before attempting to process its data (as well as ensuring that the previous 3s has elapsed).  What I want is to make a call, get its return, start the processing, make the next call, and have its data ready for the 2nd round when that first one completes after 3s, then repeat.

Comment: how do you determine when to stop getting data?

Comment: (not shown — once newValue exceeds a certain range, no further calls are made.)

Comment: yes, I know it's not shown, which is why I asked. I want to know if the range is predetermined or as a result of the `.get` - it makes a difference to the code

Comment: It's predetermined by the initial value with which doIt() is called.  E.g., the initial call to doIt() passes value=123593 or something; the next time the function recurses the value has been reduced by 50k, until it's 0 or less.

Comment: ahhh, fair enough that makes it easy

Comment: one last question - do you need a promise that resolves when all processing is done?

Comment: I presume I do, but I am open to different approaches.  I just know I need 2 conditions to be met every time, and I'd like them to be met as quickly as possible.  Thanks for your questions & willingness to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously not tested, however, I'm fairly confident this code will work

Using the fact that jQuery AJAX calls return a promise, this can be achieved as follows

```
var go = function go(initialValue) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var doIt = function doIt(value, data) {
            var p = void 0;
            if (value !== initialValue) {
                p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    var started = 0;
                    function process(ms) {
                        started = started || ms;
                        var elapsed = ms - started;
                        var done = elapsed >= 3000;
                        if (done) {
                            return resolve();
                        }
                        // do stuff with data
                        requestAnimationFrame(process);
                    }
                    process(0);
                });
            } else {
                p = Promise.resolve();
            }
            if (value > 0) {
                $.ajax("bunch/of/data.php", { param: value })
                .then(function (data) {
                    return p.then(function () {
                        return doIt(value - 50000, data);
                    });
                });
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        };
        doIt(initialValue);
    });
};
go(123593)
.then(function() {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

The same code using ONLY jQuery (i.e. no need for any Promise support in internet exploder)

```
var go = function go(initialValue) {
    var allDone = $.Deferred();
    var doIt = function doIt(value, data) {
        var p = void 0;
        if (value !== initialValue) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            var started = 0;
            function process(ms) {
                started = started || ms;
                var elapsed = ms - started;
                var done = elapsed >= 3000;
                if (done) {
                    return deferred.resolve();
                }
                // do stuff with data
                requestAnimationFrame(process);
            }
            process(0);
            p = deferred.promise();
        } else {
            p = $.when();
        }
        if (value > 0) {
            $.ajax("bunch/of/data.php", { param: value })
            .then(function (data) {
                return p.then(function () {
                    return doIt(value - 50000, data);
                });
            });
        } else {
            allDone.resolve();
        }
    };
    doIt(initialValue);
    return allDone.promise();
};
go(123593)
.then(function() {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

Comment: cool, many thanks! I'll take a look at this approach tomorrow.  (I upvoted, but I don't have sufficient rank for it to show at this point).

Comment: `internet exploder` LOL